# Eclipse The R class is not being built for my android projects

Tags: android, eclipse

My system crashed and I had to re-install all my software.
Now only like,..... half my android projects will build.  It seems like the R class is not being built.  I had this issue before, but it seemed to vanish some how.

I'm using eclipse.

I tried everything, building the project, cleaning it, then building it, nothing seems to work!

error
setContentView(R.layout.factlist); R cannot be resolved to a verable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens to me too, very often. In general when `R.java`disappears that means that there is an error somewhere in your project (which prevents this file to be generated).

Verify carefully, if everything is Ok especially in your resources files (XML files). Eclipse can help you determining what is wrong in the `Problems` window.

Comment: Hi,yhank you for the tip on the problem window.  My project resourse directory had a directory called distrabution, where I put all the files needed to send it to google market, seems like the new version of android dev tools does not like this, move the folder and it works fine!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

There are two main reasons for this. Either your import statement for importing R or there is an error in an XML file. At the top if your class, make sure your doing the following:

```
import your.pacakge.R; //make sure its not import android.R;
```

If that doesn't work, check the XML file you're working. Make sure it has no errors (open tags, misspelled tags, etc..)

Answer (score 2):

R.java  will **automatically** created.

First of all you solve other errors of your project which are not related to **R.java**.

When you will solve all other errors your R.java will created automatically.

If you are still not able to remove errors.

Just **comment** the code which has errors other then R.java

Then one by one remove comments and resolve your errors.

Hope this will help you...