# R cannot be resolved to a variable in a new project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

I can't create a new android project, neither in windows or Ubuntu! I have 2.3.3 and 2.2 and 4.0 versions of android sdk and I want to create a new project using 2.3.3 version. But after creating the project it says **R cannot be resolved to a variable**.

I have read all the questions related to this topic and I have done all the suggested solutions but none of them worked for me. (Clean Project , check Android version in Build path menu, checking xml files, lower case xml file names and etc)

Since I'm using a blank project, it's not because of some incorrect xml files or some errors in java codes.(for god sakes its a blank project!! how could it be broken?)

I don't know what to do. any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10486659/1289716) answer and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11467781/1289716)

Answer (score 7):

If cleaning the project doesn't work and if there is no problem with xml files(as it is a new project). Then go to `androidmanifest.xml`,edit it and add some spaces between the lines, save it. Now clean the project, error will vanish.

This happens because of stale `r.java` file. When we edit android manifest file,R.java is created again.

Answer (score 1):

It happen's because of error's in XML files, review all xml files and check your `Problems`  window. and then clean your project..

Hope it will work..

Comment: my project is blank!!! there's nothing in it. i create a new project and Bang! it cannot resolve R!!!

Comment: there is nothing wrong with my xml files. there's only two errors in my java files: **R cannot be resolved to a variable**

Comment: mainly it happens because of error's in xml files. if that was not the problem check your eclipse and sdk tools has all files or not.(not sure)..

Comment: can you show me your xml file..

Comment: here is my only layout file :
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: What is the use of this  tools:context=".MainActivity" and are you sure you have android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium" values in dimensions.xml file

Comment: i don't know. this is what eclipse has made! 
yeah there is three paddings there.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same problem. Here is what worked for me:

- change SDK's folder permissions: (chmod -R 777)
- add `import android.R;`
- project->Clean
- remove `import android.R;`